# How to find Requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have one `RequiredFieldValidator` on my page for my textbox and want to enable or disible . Because I want to check if the required `Option` is `true` then that `RequiredFieldValidator` will work else not for that textbox .

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReference" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtReference"
                                                                Display="None" ErrorMessage="Reference Should Not Blank !" ValidationGroup="Ac"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender9" runat="server"
                                                                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator1">
                                                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                                             <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender7" runat="server" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                                DelimiterCharacters="" EnableCaching="False" Enabled="True" FirstRowSelected="True"
                                                                MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetReference" ServicePath="" TargetControlID="txtReference">
                                                            </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

And my code that I try to do that but not works

```
if (_clients.ReferenceRequired == true)
                {
                    RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = true;
                    AutoCompleteExtender7.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false;
                    AutoCompleteExtender7.Enabled = false;
                }
```

But this not find my control on my page how can I do that?

Comment: You can't find `_clients` ? Or which control?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" - Does it fail compile? Does it not enable/disable the validator? Does it spit out green monkeys? (If it doesn't compile, then those controls might be inside a Template .. or it could be something else. Please post a *suitable problem description*.)

Comment: i want to find requiredFieldValidator and according to my condition i want that if _clients.ReferenceRequired == true then reqirdfieldValidtor work otherwise not validate

Comment: If you "want to find", then why do you have `RequiredFieldValidator1` in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the ValidationGroup to something different from the normal value you have on your page

```
   if (_clients.ReferenceRequired == true)
   {
        RequiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup = "Ac";
        AutoCompleteExtender7.ValidationGroup= "Ac";
    }
    else
    {
        RequiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup = "none";
        AutoCompleteExtender7.ValidationGroup = "none";
    }
```